# Traefik with nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I spend so much time on it and I didn't found any solution.
I already setup Traefik and the nginx container, here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: null
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
  adminer:
    image: 'adminer:latest'
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=adminer
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:db-admin.xxxx.xyz'
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - traefik.port=8080
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.xxxx.xyz"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    restart: unless-stopped
  Nginx-Pro:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: Nginx-Pro
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=Nginx-Pro
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:new.xxxx.fr
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefix.port=443"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - /var/www/nginx-pro/:/var/www/
      - /etc/nginx/nginx-pro/:/etc/nginx
```

So I also setup vhost on the server in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
I also add log to traefik conf but nothing is appening.

Here is my vhost config :

```
server {
        listen *:80;
        root /var/www/new.xxx.fr;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name new.xxx.fr www.new.xxx.fr;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And the problem is that i always have `Bad Gateway` message from Traefik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `traefik.frontend.passHostHeader` so nginx can match the `Host` header with the `server_name`.

But as this nginx is only for the one domain you match already with `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:new.xxxx.fr` you can also leave the `server_name` out of the nginx vhost config and use the default config.

Also remove `"traefix.port=443"` as you only use http between traefik and nginx, what you want is `"traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"`, you can also add `"traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"` to always redirect http to https.